# Recess framework stops me editing any files

Tags: recess

I have installed [Recess](http://www.recessframework.org/page/installation) and created an app. However I cannot do anything with the files the app created, I can not edit, delete, move the files. When I try and delete i get a FTP error of 550. Any other files on the server I can modify any way I like.

I have found the user has been set to `apache` I can manually change this but why does it set this as the owner to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're running Apache with that user, therefore, when a www app creates something, it will create it with "apache" user. Send more details.